# How can I change the checkstyle of an existing field in a pdf using itextsharp

Tags: pdf, itext

I have a pdf with existinhg fields (checkbox and radiobutton) that there check style is check , I want to change the checkstyle to cross. I am trying to do if from .Net using itextsharp.
I only found a way to define the checkstyle of a new field but not of an existing field.

Thanks for the help !